# Requisições Ajax em paralelo

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, longpolling

Estou com um sistema que tem algumas coisas que se usa long polling, isso atrapalha tudo, qualquer botão que você clica (que faz uma requisição Ajax) vai demorar porque tem o long polling executando.

O Ajax por padrão cria uma fila de requisições, quero que as requisições sejam executadas ao mesmo tempo, em paralelo.

**Por exemplo:**

Estou eu mexendo no site, enquanto isso, eu mantenho uma requisição Ajax que segura o servidor por 20seg.

Se eu clico em qualquer coisa ou até mesmo vou para outra página, tenho que esperar essa requisição de 20seg acabar.

Quero que dê para fazer diversas requisições ao mesmo tempo, igual o facebook. Alguém conhece alguma técnica? Alguma referência? Ouvi falar do *when*, mas não é isso que preciso.

**Ajax para o long polling**

```
getNotifications();
    function getNotifications(lastRequest){
        if(!lastRequest){
            lastRequest = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax/get_notifications.php?last_request=" + lastRequest,
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            success: function(data){
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                if(data['exist_news'] == true){
                    document.getElementById('notifications').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', data['news']);
                    var howMuchElement = document.getElementById('howMuchNotifications');
                    var howMuch = parseInt(howMuchElement.innerHTML);
                    var curHowMuch = data['howMuch'] + howMuch;
                    howMuchElement.innerHTML = curHowMuch;
                }
                getNotifications(data['last_request']);
            },
            error: function(error){
                showMsg(error['error']);
            }
        });
    }
```

OBS: Não tem nem um problema com o long polling.

**Um exemplo de requisição que tenho**

```
function loadModal(modalPage, modalBox, button){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/modals/" + modalPage,
        async: true,
        success: function(data){
            $("#" + modalBox + " .modal-body").html(data);  
            button.removeAttribute("onclick");  
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#" + modalBox + " .modal-body").html("<img src='/images/loading.gif'> Carregando...");
        },
        error: function(){
            $("#" + modalBox + " .modal-body").html("Ocorreu uma erro!");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Parece que você está usando requisições síncronas em vez de assíncronas. Independente de haver ou não long polling.

Comment: Uso `async: true`

Comment: na verdade eu acho que mesmo com o longpooling vc pode ir printando o output a medida que vai carregando. Ou você pode fazer o próprio ajax carregar item a itens separadamente. em vez de você realizar os loops no seu arquivo  em php faz ele exibir 1 retorno por vez e pelo ajax vc faz o numero d loops necessários. Basta ter um arquivo em php que retorna o numero de loops necessários para a a função. Fiz desta forma em 2 sistemas meus que necessitam de vários comandos ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: A função [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) do jquery por padrão executa em paralelo várias requisições sem travar o navegador e sem obedecer ordem de chamada, a requisição que terminar primeiro chama seu callback e segue em frente...

Comment: Jasar, não entendi direito a sua ideia...

Comment: Jader A. No meu ele acaba criando uma fila, o que deixa várias requisições como pendentes, até mesmo a de carregar a página.

Comment: poderia colocar o seu código pra gente dar uma olhada?

Comment: Vou colocar o código do long polling e um que uso para carregar pequenos modals (que são os mais gerais).

Comment: Se ninguém souber, vou partir para o websocket, alguém já poderia colocar referências aqui para estudo?

Answer (score 0):

A pergunta é antiga mas eis aqui uma possibilidade...

Se você chegou aqui com um problema parecido com esse e esta usando `session` no seu PHP é possível que isso seja a causa.

O PHP deixa apenas um script operar em uma sessão por vez, ele faz isso para evitar a "escrita concorrente" *(uma mesma session ser alterada por mais de um script ao mesmo tempo)*.

Uma possível solução para isso é utilizar a função `session_write_close();` o mais cedo possível para guarda os dados de sessão e fecha a sessão, liberando assim a session para outro script. Depois de utilizar a `session_write_close();` você ainda vai ser capaz de acessar a `$_SESSION` porem não vai salvar alterações nela.

> #### [session_write_close](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-write-close.php)
>
> <sup>Guarda os dados de sessão e fecha a sessão</sup>
>
> Os dados de sessão **geralmente são guardados depois que o script termina**, sem a necessidade de chamar `session_write_close();` **mas como dados de sessão são travados para evitar escritas concorrentes, apenas um script pode operar em uma sessão por vez.** Ao usar iframe/framesets junto com sessões, os frames serão lidos um a um devido à esta trava. **Pode-se reduzir o tempo** necessário para carregar todos os frames **fechando a sessão o mais cedo possível**, assim que todas as alterações na variável de sessão tiverem sido feitas.

Answer (score -1):

Quando for fazer uma requisição ajax, faça ela de forma assíncrona. Segue código em Jquery, exemplo da documentação:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  console.log('oi');
});
```

O async é ativado por default, caso queira desativar o async, o que faria o navegador aguardar a resposta do servidor para continuar qualquer tarefa, é só adicionar `async: false,`.

Mais informações a documentação oficial:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Eu uso `async: false`

Comment: Então esse é o problema, com o async:false você faz de forma não assíncrona, o que acaba travando o navegador aguardando a requisição ajax. Só remover o async.

Comment: Desculpa, acabei copiando do seu para não dar mais trabalho e esqueci de editar kkkkk, uso true.